# Find all real solutions of $\,(x^2+2)^3 = x^2 \cdot (x^4-2)^5$

Tags: real-analysis

> I want to find all real solutions of $(x^2+2)^3 = x^2 \cdot (x^4-2)^5$

I know that $-\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt2$ are the real solutions, but I only found them with Wolfram Alpha, is there any nice trick?

Comment: I'd like to say to expand the expression $(x^2+2)^3-x^2(x^4-2)^5$, factoring with the highest exponent of $x$ ($x^{22}$) and reducing to a unique fraction the appearing expression but it's still a huge job...

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}(x^2+2)^3-x^2(x^4-2)^5&=(x^2-2+4)^3-x^2(x^4-4+2)^5\\&=\text{multiple of }(x^2-2)+4^3-x^22^5\end{align}$$

and $4^3-x^22^5=2^5(2-x^2)$

So, it is multiple of $x^2-2$.

A [Sturm sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) for this polynomial could be:

$$\begin{align}P(x)&=-(x^{22}-10 x^{18}+40 x^{14}-80 x^{10}+80 x^6-x^4-36 x^2-4)\\P_1(x)&=-22 x^{21}+180 x^{17}-560 x^{13}+800 x^9-480 x^5+4 x^3+72 x\\P_2(x)&=121 x^{19}+180 x^{17}-990 x^{15}-1440 x^{13}+3080 x^{11}+4320 x^9-4400 x^7-5760x^5+2721 x^3+3218 x\\P_3(x)&=-3600 x^{16}+440 x^{14}+28800 x^{12}-3520 x^{10}-86400 x^8+10560 x^6+116289 x^4-10860 x^2-59036\\P_4(x)&=-40 x^{15}+320 x^{11}-1770 x^7-3699 x^5-3300 x^3-524 x\\P_5(x)&=-80 x^{13}+640 x^9-1179 x^7-8780 x^5-13424 x^3-6600 x\\P_6(x)&=-9 x^8-40 x^6-46 x^4-8\\P_7(x)&=-462691 x^7-4368940 x^5-10016496 x^3-4467080 x\\P_8(x)&=-20812820 x^6-68864678 x^4-40203720 x^2+3701528\\P_9(x)&=59066895082302 x^5+189869628200 x^3+94685195657 x\\P_{10}(x)&=4063670987907317204756 x^4+2372738245224372640700 x^2-218637766020203157456\\P_{11}(x)&=139378713288832284253829458583172200 x^3-13299023469119912009631063575888404 x\\P_{12}(x)&=-384752059429535971855272863800630248309583767693502589424 x^2+30473450504240693468523208014770561024032258628561923200\\P_{13}(x)&=869476347393632818032761983220428974658088759249432110238779874810962478042579916479599296 x\\P_{14}(x)&=-1.\end{align}$$

At $+\infty$ this sequence has, $--+------+++-+-$, (look at the sign of the leading terms) $6$ changes of sign. At $-\infty$ it has $-+--++-+--+----$ (look at the sign of the leading terms but change it when the degree is odd) $8$ changes of sign. So by Sturm theorem it must have $8-6=2$ real roots.

Funny numbers, eh?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what that tells us... I also dont know how you know: $=\text{multiple of }(x^2-2)+4^3-x^22^5$

Comment: Expand $(x^2-2+4)^3=\left((x^2-2)+4\right)^3$ using the binomial formula. Likewise with $(x^4-4+2)^5=\left((x^4-4)+2\right)^5=\left((x^2-2)(x^2+2)+2\right)^5$. You get a lot of terms that are multiples of $x^2-2$ and the terms $4^3$ from the first expansion and the term $x^22^5$ from the second. If a polynomial is multiple of $x^2-2=(x+\sqrt{2})(x-\sqrt{2})$ then $\pm\sqrt{2}$ are roots of it.

Comment: Does that show, that $+-\sqrt2$ are the only real roots?

Comment: No, that only shows that they are roots. There is a no-brain algorithm to count how many real roots a polynomial has. It is called Sturm's theorem [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem]. This can save you from having to come up with tricks. So, if Sturm's tells you there are only two real roots, then those are the only ones.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bit easier considering $(y+2)^3-y(y^2-2)^5$?

Comment: No, the computer doesn't even blink at the difference, and this symmetry is likely to not appear in the next problem.